# AS3/Flash: combobox and textinput interaction

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, combobox, textinput

I'd like to know if it's possible (AS3/Flash CS5):

- To reset a combobox to it's prompt state when focusing (clicking) in a textinput field.
- To empty a textinput when a value is selected in the combobox.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

Many thanks **Kieran**. I prefer

```
myComboBox.selectedIndex=0;
```

than

```
myComboBox.selectedItem=myComboBox.prompt;
```

Due to the index.

Is there any situation where the second one could be more useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add a listener for each of scenario. Something like this:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

inputText_txt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clearComboBox);
comboBox.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, clearTextBox);

function clearComboBox(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    comboBox.selectedItem = -1; 
}

function clearTextBox(e:Event):void
{
    inputText_txt.text = ""; 
}
```

Comment: Yeah `comboBox.selectedItem = -1; ` is probably the best way to do it. Using selectedItem will return to the prompt value but if you wanted the combobox to return to a specific item on the dropdown list then `comboBox.selectedIndex = 1;` is the way to go.